# Cannot disable two finger scrolling

Tags: windows-10, scrolling, synaptics-touchpad

**OS**: Windows 10 Pro (Build 17134.137)

**Touchpad driver**: Synaptics Pointing Device from Lenovo (version 19.0.17.115, September 19, 2016)

**PC**: Thinkpad W520

Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to additional mouse options.

[image: UltraNav settings screenshot]

2. Navigate to TouchPad Properties.

[image: TouchPad Properties screenshot]

3. Ensure that two finger scrolling is disabled.

[image: Two finger scrolling setting screenshot]

As you can see from the last screenshot, two finger scrolling is disabled on my system, yet the touch-pad still begins to scroll when I have two fingers placed on it. It's jarring and irritating and I'm not used to it at all.

Strangely enough, the setting seems to stick when I open UltraNav settings and close it. But two finger scrolling returns after a restart. I don't know if this is an issue with a driver or my configuration of Windows 10...

I've tried the following:

1. Rolling back the driver, which didn't resolve the issue.
2. Deleting the driver and re-installing it via Windows update and from Lenovo's website. Also didn't resolve the issue.

Does anyone have a permanent fix, like maybe a registry edit that completely disables all additional touch-pad gestures like this one?

Answer (score 1):

Though I cannot provide a definitive answer, you should find the settings for the touchpad in two Registry keys:

[image: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics]

1. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics` (There may be more than one set of keys.)

[image: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults\2FingerGestures]

2. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults\2FingerGestures`

The first contains user settings and the second defaults, to which the device might be reverting after reboot.

Though I don't condone poking around randomly in the Registry, you might try the following procedure to find locations being changed, using a third-party tool, such as Nirsoft's [Registry Changes View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html).

- First, *back up the Registry before making any changes*.
- Open the Registry comparison tool.
- Make a snapshot of the Registry saved to a convenient folder.
- Change the Synaptics Touchpad two-finger scrolling setting and apply it.
- Make a second Registry snapshot.
- Compare it with the previous one.

[image: Registry Changes View]

On *my laptop*, the value `DisableGestures` changed from 56 to 60, so it appears that the two-finger-scroll setting is stored as the bit in the *fours* place.

Once you discover this for *your* laptop, you can then change ownership of the key to [*TrustedInstaller*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/irenak/2007/01/30/sysk-277-how-to-bring-back-the-trustedinstaller/) to prevent it being changed back by the system. You can also change the defaults in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTP\Defaults\2FingerGestures` to suit your preferences.

You might also make a .REG export of the key with your preferred settings, to revert after a driver or Windows update changes settings for you.